# Encrypt URL with PHP Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, url, encryption

I have developed a website with PHP Codeigniter. It consists of many controllers and views. I want to encrypt the URL of the site to hide the controller and function name. Currently, the URL looks like this :

> www.sitename.com/controller_name/function_name

I don't want the users to see the controller and function names. Is it possible to do this now because the site is almost complete. Is there any shortcut of doing this? Please Help

Comment: you should have decided on this EARLY in the production process. "your $X millions super sports car will be finished tomorrow". "Ok, that's nice, but you can convert it into a submarine instead?"

Comment: I don't know about "encrypt", but you can easily change the URL into anything and then route to the appropriate controller/function.  Read the docs:  https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html

Comment: As @Sparky says, use URI routing. Than just make rewrite rules in .htaccess file to disallow original paths approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use codeigniter URI Routing to remove your controller name from URL.

```
$route['url_name'] = 'controller_name/function_name';

This `www.sitename.com/url_name` will look go to `www.sitename.com/controller_name/function_name`

$route['url_name/(:any)'] = 'controller_name/$1';

This will only change your controller name.. `controller_name` to `url_name`
```

Comment: where should I edit this code? I mean in which file?

Comment: In your `application/config/routes.php` file